# React/ React-native project / "export 'requireNativeComponent' was not found in 'react-native-web/dist/index'

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have got a google maps route project consisting of 3 folders:
App Frontend,
Admin dashboard Frontend,
Shared backend for App and Admin dashboard.

- node -v v16.15.0
- npm -v 8.9.0
- git version 2.36.0.windows.1
- npm view react version 18.1.0 (In package.json - "react": "^16.11.0", "react-dom": "^16.11.0",)
- npm view react-native version 0.68.2
- npm install expo-cli --global  (few vulnerabilities)
- expo --version 5.4.3

I should only develop in App Frontend.
I have set up react native environment correctly.
Navigated to project directory in Terminal.
Ran so many following commands: (Because each time got some errors or suggestions)

- expo start
- expo doctor --fix-dependencies
- removed node modules
- npm i --force
- npm install --legacy-peer-deps
- npm start
- removed node modules + package-lock.json
- npm install --force
- npm start
  -expo install expo-font@8.2.1 react-native-gesture-handler@1.6.0
- npm install --force  expo-font@8.2.1 react-native-gesture-handler@1.6.0
- deleted node_modules folder and package-lock.json.
- npm cache clean --force
- npm install --force
- npm start
- npm update --force
- npm audit fix
- npm install --force react@16.11.0 react-dom@16.11.0
- npm start
- Terminal error - ./node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/components/MapView.js:1011:2
  "export 'requireNativeComponent' was not found in 'react-native-web/dist/index'
  1009 |
  1010 | const nativeComponent = Component =>

> 1011 |   requireNativeComponent(Component, MapView, {
> |  ^
> 1012 |     nativeOnly: {
> 1013 |       onChange: true,
> 1014 |       onMapReady: true,

Browser's Console error  - Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined

Answer (score 0):

It helped by commenting requireNativeComponent out everywhere it is in MapView.js file, in functions.